# file size preservation when automatically transferring files

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, smb

I have an FTP server that users are uploading music or talk programs to. I have a server that will automatically, through time based scheduling, grab these files in certain directories. One of the issues we are experiencing is that a file can still be uploading when the server grabs the file. Is there any way to avoid this?

I am pretty sure it is because the upload is FTP and windows uses smb. What I have done in the interim is used a computer in between the FTP server and the server the audio is supposed to go on and put a free mirroring software on it. It has alleviated some of th problems  but it has been unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a PowerShell script in the past to accomplish this. The `Move-Item` command handles this well. Create a loop that looks for files and tell it to move stuff that it finds.

```
while ($true) {
    Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | Move-Item -Destination $destPath -Force
    Sleep 5
}
```

I set the PS Script to execute in Task Scheduler on Startup. It gets a bit trickier when moving to a network share due to permissions but YMMV.

You can even filter what you want to move. This example will not move folders:

```
Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | Where {!$_.psiscontainer} | Move-Item -Destination $destPath -Force
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still a little new to powershell. I didn't think of doing a loop. I like the idea of the move also but I'm concerned about the FTP aspect. If I have a large file, will it move it in mid transfer? Is the move with powershell different than the move command in command prompt?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to see if a move can be recursive like a mirror. Can powershell do a mirror and delete the source?

Comment: @Geerdes A move functions like a copy then delete source. If the copy fails, the delete also fails. Also, because of file lock, the file won't move until FTP is done with it. We had success with very large and slow transfers (>5GB, up to 3 hours) over a slow link with this method.

Comment: @Geerdes To do a recursive move, add the -recursive parameter to the Get-ChildItem command.

Comment: So the recursive move would work, would it keep it recursive in the destination? I am really glad to hear that it waits for the FTP to finish with it.

Comment: I just ran this and it solved one of my problems, but I just uploaded at 54mb file to our FTP and the script yanked it before the whole thing got there. it transferred the file at 20mb instead of the 54. Any additional ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's working differently for you. Perhaps a different version of PowerShell, or OS, or FTP software. We were using 2008 R2 and IIS. It seems likely that the file lock dropped, possibly due to an aborted FTP connection. You could add in extra logic such as validating a condition before moving. Some possibilities include matching a file hash (WSUS names files with SHA1 hashes for example or passing a second file that's filtered with the hash info), or checking your FTPS logs for a "transfer complete" message.